# What if I turn autopoweroff to OFF and standby ON, on my MacBook Pro late 2016?

Tags: sleep, macbook, battery, standby

if my standby delay is set to 2700 seconds will my laptop hibernate after 45 minutes. I don't see any clear explanation about the difference between autopoweroff and standby in any of the posts. What should I set them to, to keep a balance between the amount of my battery consumed and my ssd write cycles. I set it to 45 mins because I thought it was optimum for me as I usually wake up my computer before that or else I am done for the day.

Also do any if these features have anything to do with my battery consumption while **TURNED OFF**? As I see a battery drain of about 1 % every 6 hours when my MacBook is turned off. I want to know why is it said that you can put a Macbook to sleep for months and wake it up and resume your work right where you left it off. How can we achieve this if battery continues to drain like that. I did refer to friend who has been a MacBook user all his life and said that there is nothing wrong with my device as this is a common thing. I would like you to elaborate on this.

Comment: How did you get a battery drain figure of 1% every 6 hours? If you wake it up to check the state of the battery then each wake cycle is going to drain the battery and not represent the battery loss when powered off. Standby stores the state of the work applications etc so it resumes from where you left it.

Comment: Its just an approximate idea. I wasn't waking it up every time. When I wake it up the next day after about 12 hours I see a 2% decrease and when I wake it up in the evening after about 7 hours I see a decrease of 1 %. I have noticed this over an entire week.